# What happens if I delete dmraid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS from a live-USB and have it run alongside my Windows 7 installation.

On the installation screen for Ubuntu, at the partition page, I get this error:

```
No root file system is defined.

Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

However on this page, nothing is clickable and it doesn't show any partitions.

I looked it up and I found a possible solution is to type in the Linux terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

I am wondering what the repercussions are of deleting dmraid and if it will do anything disastrous to my Windows boot.

And if deleting dmraid isn't a smart idea, are there any other suggestions on what I should do?

BTW I am on an Acer S5-391 and I think it has a RAID 0 SSD configuration.

Comment: How are you installing Ubuntu? From within Windows or by booting from the live CD/USB?

Comment: from a live usb

Comment: Well, `apt-get remove` simply uninstalls (Linux) programs so it won't affect your Windows install in any way. I have no idea if it will help you or if it is a good idea though.

Comment: Try 13.10 just to see if it can handle it better. You'd probably update in April (14.04 LTS) either way. If that doesn't work either, provide `fdisk -l`, `ls /dev/mapper`, `cat /proc/partitions`, `dmraid -s -s` or similar so we can get a better idea of your configuration.